# What are these component on behind of this circuit?

Tags: pcb

This is a circuit which was inside a rechargeable light. Purpose of this circuit is to supply power for charging mobile phone. I see some components on behind of this circuit what are those?
behind:
[image: behind] 
front:
[image: front]

Comment: I see 5 resistors and an IC (probably a linear voltage regulator).

Comment: I see a diode and an inductor on the non-copper side. So it could be a switching regulator.

Comment: If you do not recognize these basic components, what is your purpose of knowing what they are ?

Comment: I see a Rhinoceros.

Comment: If this charges mobile phones; I bet half of the phones explode due to faulty chargers 
*I hope you all get the phone explosion reference*

Comment: @FakeMoustache I couldn't recognize those resistor because before this I haven't seen resistors like them in my books :)

Comment: @ammar.cma I don't have any plan to charge my mobile with that cheap Chinese device! I just opened the box and I was curious about those components on copper side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top pictures shows 5 resistors and something that appears to be in a SOT-89 package.  It is probably a transistor or voltage regulator.

The bottom picture shows a USB connector, 2 electrolytic caps, a diode, and probably a inductor.